# Will the two following ObservableCollections function the same?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

Assume the following:

```
Public ObservableCollection<string> SomeCollection;
Public ObservableCollection<string> SomeOtherCollection
{
    get{ return SomeCollection; }
    set{ SomeCollection = value; }
}
```

Both are bound to a `ListBox` in a WPF UI using

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeOtherCollection} />
```

Assuming this, will both update automatically? To my understanding, the first will, but I know absolutely nothing as to the functionality of the second.

**Note:** This is a rough example. Please don't be hyperliteral with me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example will not be able to bind to the UI (only properties may be bound to the UI in wpf), however if you changed it to:

```
Public ObservableCollection<string> SomeCollection { get; set; }
```

They would be equivalent.  The `get; set;` is just shorthand for your second example.  If you ever want to add any extra logic in either the getter or the setter (like implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`), you would have to write out the whole thing.  If you just want the simple get and set, the above is the same thing.